# Which is better in implementing click listener?

Tags: android

Which is a good practice in implementing click listener and why? Or is there a better way other than the two? Thanks.

First :

```
    sampleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            // do something
        }

    });
```

Second : implement OnClickListener then override onClick method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're technically doing the 2nd thing with the 1st one. The 1st case uses whats called an anonymous class which implements OnClickListener, but since is anonymous, doesn't have a class name and isn't editable from external classes. Explicitably implementing OnClickListener is useful if you expect to use the same onClick functionality in multiple different locations, or if the click code is long

Comment: Are they the same in terms of memory consumption?

Comment: If you're copying and pasting the code multiple times to add the same click functionality to multiple objects, then its most likely that the compiler would make multiple anonymous classes meaning slightly more memory for the program. However, if you're just defining it the one time then should have the same footprint. Since anonymous classes are mainly a compiler functionality, I'd imagine there wouldn't be any significant difference from fully defined classes

Answer (score 3):

The third option is to set the listener directly in your XML layout:

```
android:onClick="myClickHandler"
```

and then implement it in your Activity:

```
public void myClickHandler(View v){
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: i hope the OP sees this xml method.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is used when you want to perform the action only for a particular case, if many click events require the same action then use the second one.